Snowflake Macro Variables
I have a dataset that I need to work with, every month a new set of columns are added with various names but have the month and year in the middle of the column name. I.e.
Column_1_May_24_hello
Column_2_May_24_bye
Column_1_June_24_hello
Column_2_June_24_bye

and so on.
Each month I want to reference the new set of columns. I currently have to do a control/replace to replace all the months and years with the new ones in the code.
Is there anyway to adapt the code so I wouldn't need to do find/replace? I'm used to SAS where I'd have macro variables used as column names or perhaps run do loops to create a new dataset with each month_year as a row and Hello and Bye (Examples) as the columns.
Any help with this would be greatly appreciated as not sure where to start.

Hi - adding new columns to a dataset every month is a really bad design (anti-pattern). I suggest you fix your data model design rather than trying to code round your design issues

Yes agreed, unfortunately I can't control the data model I just have to work with it. I've got tickets raised to try and discuss but I still need to be able to work efficiently in the mean time. Very frustrating and I can easily see how the data could change to make life easier.

Quick search for "dynamic sql in snowflake" found the execute immediate statement.  https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/execute-immediate

@Tom Thanks! One thing I couldn't understand from this documentation was that is it that each column with the month and year would have to be listed out and changed each time? Or is it possible to create a variable for month and year and put it into each column that has it? Asking because there are 20+ columns that would need to change. And therefore easier to find and replace the normal code. The documentation is quite complicated for me as a newbie to this.

As with any code generation problem you first need to know what code you want to generate.  It is not at all clear what code you want to generate. Or even what is your source of the date string that want to use to generate the variable names.
